# Create a dynamic table from a java.util.Map

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm developing a web application in JSF 2.0. In my application I need a table for viewing presences.

I have a `Map<Date, List<Presence>>` in my 'PresenceService' bean.

The Presence object has a Person object (with name and surname) and a boolean present/not present.

I'd like to create a table that looks like this:

```
                 monday     tuesday        wednesday    ...
Name Person 1    present    not present    present      ...
Name Person 2    present    present        present      ...
...              ...        ...            ...          ...
```

Which JSF components could I use to create such a table? Or should I not be using a Map for this? I tried creating a table myself with `<ui:repeat>`'s but failed to do so.
As wel the colums as the rows can be dynamic since the user can choose a period and a range of persons.

**EDIT: solution (see answer Balus C)**

This works like a charm:

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
            <ui:repeat value="#{aanwezigheidController.siAanwezigheidService.datums}" var="datumHeader">
                <th>
                <h:outputText value="#{datumHeader}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                </h:outputText>
                </th>
            </ui:repeat>
            </tr>
            <ui:repeat value="#{aanwezigheidController.siAanwezigheidService.aanwezigheidSiRijen}" var="aanwRij">
                <tr>
                    <td>#{aanwRij.persoon.naam} #{aanwRij.persoon.voornaam}</td>

                <ui:repeat value="#{aanwezigheidController.siAanwezigheidService.datums}" var="datumCell">
                    <td>
                    <h:outputText value="aanwezig" rendered="#{aanwRij.aanwezighedenMap[datumCell].aanwezig}" />
                    <h:outputText value="afwezig" rendered="#{!aanwRij.aanwezighedenMap[datumCell].aanwezig}" />
                    </td>
                </ui:repeat>

                </tr>
            </ui:repeat>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A double nested `<ui:repeat>` should be fine. The standard JSF implementation does not offer something like `<h:columns>` to represent dynamic columns, but component libraries [RichFaces](http://jboss.org/richfaces) and [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) have respectively [`<rich:columns>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_columns.html) and [`<p:columns>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf) for exactly this purpose. You may want to take a look at it.

With alone a `Map<Date, List<Presence>>`, it is not possible to pick a specific person to present the row data for all columns. You basically need a `Map<Date, Map<Person, List<Presence>>`, or a separate `List<Date>` representing the dynamic columns and a separate `List<Presence>` where the `Presence` in turn has `Person` and `Map<Date, Boolean>` properties so that a specific date can be picked for the columns.

Comment: I think I'll go for the second option. I'll let you know when I'm ready. Thank you very much, I was really stuck.